# How can I build the fastest mining XMR rig?

Tags: monerod, gpu-mining

I'm thinking 2 R9-295x2 in quad crossfire configuration. Can anyone tell me what software to use? I don't mind PAYING US dollars for software as long as it's reasonable.  I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO INSTALL MOST OF THE GARBAGE SOFTWARE ON THE NET. I did get the monerod software running but will I get a decent hashrate with the the AMD cards? I was getting like 40 with my Zotac Amp Extreme 980ti which is just atrocious.

I really believe in Monero and I want to help it succeed by running a full node from home. I would like to at least break even since I plan to accumulate the currency.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer provided, just one note on this:

> I did get the monerod software running but will I get a decent
>   hashrate with the the AMD cards? I was getting like 40 with my Zotac
>   Amp Extreme 980ti which is just atrocious.

This is because the `monerod` is using only the CPU, as far as I'm aware. For GPU, there is dedicated mining software like [Wolf's](https://github.com/wolf9466/wolf-xmr-miner/releases), [Claymore](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=638915.0), or [sgminer-gm](https://github.com/genesismining/sgminer-gm/releases).

Once set up, please use one of the [smaller pools](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/5cvkqe/miners_please_help_the_network_and_diversify_3/) to help decentralize mining. Also, feel free to ask for help on IRC channel #monero-mining on [freenode](https://webchat.freenode.net/), or on Monero mining [sub-Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/).

Answer (score 3):

> I'm thinking 2 R9-295x2 in quad crossfire configuration. Can anyone tell me what software to use?

The Wolf or Claymore miners [compared](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/150/performance-comparison-of-wolfs-open-source-compared-with-claymores-closed-sou) in this question are the most popular options

The definition of "a decent hasrate" is subjective and profitability depends on more than just your equipment and software. Electricity costs are always important to consider.

> I really believe in Monero and I want to help it succeed by running a full node from home.

Running a full node helps the network and mining helps even more. Choosing a small mining pool or solo mining and avoiding large pools like [Minergate](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/which-entities-are-related-to-bytecoin-and-minergate) will lead to higher variance with your payouts but are great for network [decentralization](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/769/how-decentralized-is-monero-mining).